# Problem in detecting a new usb device in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

I want a python script that will trigger once any device like: a keyboard, a mouse, headphones, charger, etc. For eg: if I plug in my optical mouse, it should print the name of usb device in this case, it is a dell mouse. basically it is a project all about checking for a new usb device and printing that it is connected or disconnected + it's name. I have al ready viewed [How to detect a new usb device is connected on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495206/how-to-detect-a-new-usb-device-is-connected-on-python)
and on Github too! but didn't get the proper solution. any help would be appreciated. In case it matters, I am on Windows 10 20H1 and currently running python 3.10

Comment: Can you update your post with your code, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Sorry but i don't have any code i just want code to detect usb devices

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.